# React onClick not firing on component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I'm using Remix with React and TS.
I have a simple class component called Map.tsx, that is used in index.tsx.

#### Map.tsx

```
class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.regionClicked = this.regionClicked.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => alert("ciao")}>a</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

#### index.tsx

```
import Map from "../components/index/map/Map";

class Index extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you have posted is fine (tested in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-khorana-h1sd8)). The issue must come from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using the Scripts tag in the root.tsx file.
Example available [here](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/jokes#javascript)

```
import { Scripts } from "remix";

function Document({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode; title?: string }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Header />
        {children}
        <Footer />
        <Scripts />
        {process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? <LiveReload /> : null}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```